# How to add row number to an MySQL display using ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I use ROW_NUMBER() function (required) to display row numbers on Mysql table display?

```
mysql> select * from work;
+------+-----------+
| name | work_days |
+------+-----------+
| john |         5 |
| jane |         7 |
| jane |         2 |
| john |         3 |
+------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Without using ROW_NUMBER():

```
mysql> SELECT name, 
    -> AVG(work_days) AS workday_average, 
    -> COUNT(*) as count
    -> FROM work
    -> GROUP BY name
    -> HAVING workday_average > 2
    -> ORDER BY workday_average ASC, count DESC;
+------+-----------------+-------+
| name | workday_average | count |
+------+-----------------+-------+
| john |          4.0000 |     2 |
| jane |          4.5000 |     2 |
+------+-----------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Errors below when trying to add a row number column using ROW_NUMBER().

```
mysql> SELECT name, 
    -> ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY work_days) as row_num,
    -> AVG(work_days) AS workday_average, 
    -> COUNT(*) as count
    -> FROM work
    -> GROUP BY name
    -> HAVING workday_average > 2
    -> ORDER BY workday_average ASC, count DESC;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY work_days) as row_num,
AVG(work_days) AS workday_ave' at line 2
mysql>
```

Comment: Please mentione the MySQL version?

Comment: As Tim said, it doesn't make sense, but it does work, given sufficiently new MariaDB: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=4fb5cc7545f248f3e2101c9df6202103).

Comment: @user1972031 . . . You are getting a syntax error on `OVER (PARTITION`.  That means that your database does not support window functions, so you cannot do what you want on this database.  You can upgrade the database to a more recent version.

Comment: Mysql version is 8.0.15 

linux:MYSQL$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 8.0.15 for osx10.14 on x86_64 (Homebrew)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window functions evaluate after `GROUP BY` aggregation has happened, so it doesn't make much sense to use a partition on the `name`, since each record at that point would be guaranteed to have a distinct name.  Most likely, you want something like this:

```
SELECT
    name, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AVG(work_days), COUNT(*) DESC) AS row_num,
    AVG(work_days) AS workday_average, 
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM work
GROUP BY
    name
HAVING
   workday_average > 2
ORDER BY
    workday_average,
    count DESC;
```

But this of course assumes that you are using MySQL 8+.  If not, then `ROW_NUMBER` won't be available.

Comment: As the error mentions MariaDB, MariaDB needs to be at least 10.2+.

Comment: Mysql version is 8.0.15.

linux:MYSQL$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 8.0.15 for osx10.14 on x86_64 (Homebrew).  I thought 8.0.15 should be able to have ROW_NUMBER() function?

Comment: Yes, it seems that you are running MySQL 8+.

Comment: @Amadan: Yes, Thanks for the help. It worked fine now after I upgraded Mysql to version 15.1 and MariaDB to version 10.3.15

Comment: `mysql -V` reports the version of the MySQL _client_. The issue was that the _server_ was a pre-10.2 MariaDB.